# XML & Variable String

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a script where I have xml that generates a PDF.

Problem is that some of the names in our ERP have the &.

So I have code like this

```
else{soTable += company;}
```

When that company name has an & it fails out.  I just need to know how to get around the error and display the & properly no matter where it is in the returned string.

Comment: You need to use an XML API instead of concatenating or parsing XML by hand.  Then, everything will just work.

Comment: have you tried &amp;? This is the XML-entity for the '&' character. On the other Hand...  using a lib/api, like SLaks suggested may be the best way to go...

Comment: I don't think you all are understanding.  I would have added &amp if it was just a hardcoded name.  Company in the code above is a variable.